# Dynamic output namespace for imported templates

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xml-namespaces

I have a simple XSL that uses an import:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns="http://ex1">
  <xsl:import href="import.xsl" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ROOT>
      <FIRST />
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </ROOT>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The imported stylesheet is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="elm">
        <ELM/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now i want that the imported templates also use the default namespace `http://ex1` as defined in the main stylesheet. I expected:

```
<ROOT xmlns="http://ex1">
   <FIRST/>
   <ELM/>
</ROOT>
```

But I got:

```
<ROOT xmlns="http://ex1">
   <FIRST/>
   <ELM xmlns=""/>
</ROOT>
```

The imported stylesheet must output to the namespacee that the main template defines.

**What I have tried**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns="http://ex1">
  <xsl:import href="import_nsparam.xsl" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ROOT>
      <FIRST />
      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:with-param name="ns">http://ex1</xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </ROOT>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this import:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="elm">
        <xsl:param name="ns"/>
        <xsl:element name="ELM" namespace="{$ns}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works but it requires a lot of biolerplate code.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try `<xsl:with-param name="ns" select="namespace-uri-for-prefix('', document('')/*)"/>` instead of `<xsl:with-param name="ns">http://ex1</xsl:with-param>`, to not have to hard code the namespace twice in the stylesheet.